# Server Response to Browser: calling the doGet Method Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, get, httpresponse

I'm creating a basic server that accepts the HTTP protocol directly from the browser. What I want to do is use the DoGet Method to be able to respond to the GET Request with an html page. Ordinarily, you would accomplish the same result with servlets, but for the exercise I am using interfaces MyHttpRequest, MyHttpResponse, MyHttpHandler to perform the same functions as a servlet. This is what I have so far:

```
public class Server implements MyHttpRequest, MyHttpResponse, MyHttpHandler {

private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html; charset=windows-1252";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Server server = new Server();

    ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(8080);//localhost
    Socket socket = serversocket.accept();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    System.out.println(line);

    if(line.equals("GET / HTTP/1.1"))
    {
        System.out.println("Request works. Responding now...");

        //PROBLEM CODE //--------------------------------------------//
        doGet(problem_parameter1, problem_parameter2,);
        //-----------------------------------------------------------//
    }

    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out, true);

    //finally {
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    socket.close();
    serversocket.close();
    //}
}
```

My DoGet Method:

```
@Override
public void doGet(MyHttpRequest request, MyHttpResponse response) 
{
    //response
        response.getContentType();
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<html><body>");
        pw.println("<h1>Welcome to our Site!</h1>");
        pw.println("<p>We hope you enjoy your stay.</p>");
        pw.println("</body></html>");
        pw.close();
}
```

My problem is that I am confused as to what I am supposed to use for parameters of the doGet Method in Main. The point of the exercise is to be able to use the doGet Method to send the HTML to the Localhost:8080 -- but i don't know how this is possible without using JSP or Servlets.

Is there something I am missing here? I've researched everything I can on using doGet, but I was under the impression the Servlet automatically calls the doGet or doPost when it needs them. If I'm not using a servlet, how should I call the doGet Method?

Any helpful suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going about this wrong, making the class implement `MyHttpRequest` and `MyHttpResponse`. Those two classes should be objects created by the server and *passed* to the `doGet` method.

You should use a better OOP approach. For instance, let the `Server` be able to register `MyHandlers`. Something like

```
public interface MyHandler {
    void doGet(MyHttpRequest request, MyHttpResponse response);
    void doPost(MyHttpRequest request, MyHttpResponse response);
}
public class MyHandlerImpl implements MyHandler {
    @Override
    public void doGet(MyHttpRequest request, MyHttpResponse response) {}
    @Override
    public void doPost(MyHttpRequest request, MyHttpResponse response) {}
}
public class Server {
    private Map<String, MyHander> handlers = new HashMap<String, MyHandler>();
    public void registerHandler(String path, MyHandler handler) {
        handler.put(path, handler);
    }
}
```

You can handle all your operations in the `Server` class. For instance when a request comes into the server, you'll parse the request and wrap it into a `MyHttpRequest` object. You'll first parse it add get what type of request it is, and to which handler (*"servlet"*) to sent it to (just like a normal servlet would do, based on a url mapping). Based on the type of reqeust, you call either `doGet` or `doPost` of the handler. So it may look something like this

```
public class Server {
    ...
    public void handleServerRequest(InputStream is) {
        // parse the input stream
        String path = // get from stream
        String requestType = // get from stream
        MyHandler handler = handlers.get(path);
        MyHttpRequest request = new MyHttpRequest();
        // set request properties.
        MyHttpResponse response = new MyHttpResponse();
        if ("GET".equals(requestType)) {
            handler.doGet(request, response);
        } else if ("POST".equals(requestType)) {
            handler.doPost(request, response);
        } else {
            throws new BadRequestException(..);
        }
    }
}
```

So after you start your `Server`, for every request that comes in, just past the `InputStream` to the `handleServerRequest` method of the `Server` and let it do its job. Something like

```
public class ServerInstance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.registerHandler(new MyHandlerImpl());

        while (true) {
            // if request comes get input stream
            server.handlerServerRequest(intputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

A simpler case is just to use one `MyHandler` for the `Server` class, so you don't have to worry about mapping them, but a real servlet containers allow more than one servlet to be added, and are mapped to an URL. The Servlet container knows which servlet to send the request to, base on the preconfigure url mappings.

As far as this concern:

> "but I was under the impression the Servlet automatically calls the doGet or doPost when it needs them"

Actually the servlets don't call their own methods. These calls are handled by the servlet container, in a similar way my design example works. It may make more sense if you rename `MyHandler` to `MyServlet`, and the `Server` would be, say Tomcat. `Server` allows you to register multiple `MyServlets`, and handles the incoming requests and hands them off to the servlets